# Include libxml2 in Wireshark plugin (Windows)

Tags: c, wireshark

I would like to write my own C-dissector-plugin for Wireshark. I've already downloaded and build Wireshark on my Windows machine and have also added the plugin files (according to https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWindows.html). Everything compiled, Wireshark runs and my plugin is also visible.

Messages of the protocol I want to dissect are defined as length-prefixed xml objects, very simple. To give myself a quicker overview of the interesting contents of each message I wanted to create a seperate dissector for it - hence use libxml2.

However, I am not very familiar with cmake and the build chain and I do not want to break my "running" system.

Long story short: How can I include the libxml2-lib in my packet.c - file so I can use it in VS and compile it? I think other sources of Wireshark already using libxml2 and it's library is contained as libxml2.dll in the final Wireshark build.

Any help is appreciated, Cheers